# how to clear CCGLView color in cocos2d 2.0 of an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, uiview, cocos2d-iphone

install cocos2d framework and create a cocos2d project, and replace the method below.

i have camera view and a CCGLView, i want to clear CCGLView color so that i can see the camera view while i see the CCGLView

if i comment the code "[window_ bringSubviewToFront:director_.view];", i can see the camera view, if i bring the director.view(glview) to the front, i cannot see camera view.

could anyone can help me on this?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create the main window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    // Create an CCGLView with a RGB565 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 0-bits
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];


    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;        

    // Display FSP and SPF
    [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

    // set FPS at 60
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director_ setView:glView];

    // for rotation and other messages
    [director_ setDelegate:self];
    [window_ addSubview:director_.view];


    director_.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    director_.view.opaque = NO;

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //director_.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    glView.opaque = NO;    

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    cameraView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    cameraView.opaque = NO;
    cameraView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [window_ addSubview:cameraView];

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

@try
    {
        imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
        imagePicker.toolbarHidden = YES;
        imagePicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
        imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(imagePicker.cameraViewTransform, 1.0, 1.3);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        [imagePicker release];
        imagePicker = nil;
    }
    @finally
    {
        if(imagePicker)
        {
            [cameraView addSubview:[imagePicker view]];
            [cameraView release];
        }
    }

    [window_ bringSubviewToFront:director_.view];

    // 2D projection
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
//  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    // If the 1st suffix is not found and if fallback is enabled then fallback suffixes are going to searched. If none is found, it will try with the name without suffix.
    // On iPad HD  : "-ipadhd", "-ipad",  "-hd"
    // On iPad     : "-ipad", "-hd"
    // On iPhone HD: "-hd"
    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

    // and add the scene to the stack. The director will run it automatically when the view is displayed.
    [director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer scene]]; 


    // Create a Navigation Controller with the Director

    /*
    navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
    navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;
     */

    // set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
//  [window_ addSubview:navController_.view];   // Generates flicker.
    //[window_ setRootViewController:navController_];

    // make main window visible
    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];    

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to 1.0 framework and it works, hope it will help others

```
//
//  HelloWorldLayer.m
//  arcocos2dv1
//
//  Created by Max on 13-4-10.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2013年. All rights reserved.
//


// Import the interfaces
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

// HelloWorldLayer implementation
@implementation HelloWorldLayer

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        // create and initialize a Label
        CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello Augmented" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:40];

        // ask director the the window size
        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        // position the label on the center of the screen
        label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );

        // add the label as a child to this Layer
        [self addChild: label];

        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"explosion.caf"];
    }
    return self;
}


// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc
{
    // in case you have something to dealloc, do it in this method
    // in this particular example nothing needs to be released.
    // cocos2d will automatically release all the children (Label)

    // don't forget to call "super dealloc"
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```